# How to handle error validation message with nested object in React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Hello I am currently working on my own project.

I used React Hook Form for my Add Profile menu.

But I have problem when I want to send a error validation message in input with nested object, like this.

// #01 Example of working error validation message.

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="name"
  className="some-class"
  placeholder="Last Name"
  {...register("last_name", {
   required: {
   value: true,
    message: 'Last Name is required'
  },
  minLength: {
     value: 2,
     message: '* Last name must be at least 2 characters long'
    }
  })}
 />
```

// #02 Example of nested object input (not working)

```
<div className="form-control w-full max-w-xs">
 <label htmlFor="street_name" className="label">
  <span className="label-text font-semibold"> Address </span>
 </label>
 <textarea
  id="street_name"
  placeholder="Address"
  className="textarea some-class"
  {...register("address.street_name", {
    required: true,
    message: '* Address is required'
  })}
 ></textarea>
 <p className="text-error text-xs py-1 px-1">
  {errors.address?.street_name?.message}
 </p>
</div>
```

The second input (#02) error validation message did not working because it's have a nested object in the Register field, I think the the error message it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define the `message` outside of the rule.

Try this instead in the register rules:

```js
{...register("address.street_name", {
    required: '* Address is required'
})
```

or

```js
{...register("address.street_name", {
    required: { value: true, message: "* Address is required" }
}
```

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-bessie-3t4p7v)